# Getting duration value as double

Tags: c++, duration, c++-chrono

Let's say, I have following duration value:

```
auto duration=12h+15min+99s+99ms;
```

I want to know how many hours that is (as double value).

When I do `auto hours=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(duration)`, I get `hours.count()` which is `int`. What is the right way to get the value for the whole duration expressed as double?

Comment: This sounds like elementary math to me. A minute is 1/60th of an hour, so dividing minutes by 60 gives you how many hours that is, and then adding that to the total hours gives you the combined total? Lather, rinse, repeat, for seconds and milliseconds. I do not see any valid reason to use anything in the chrono library for this. Which part of this simple, mathematical calculation is unclear to you?

Comment: yes, of course. What I'm asking is if there is an easy/default way to get the value I want from the chrono library

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'd like to introduce a counterexample - having an initial state, iterating over a range with iterator and a sentinel, and applying some logic / function to them is elementary. Yet we do have `std::accumulate`. I can very much see the sense of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using namespace std::chrono;

// Create a double-based hours duration unit
using dhours = duration<double, hours::period>;

// Assign your integral-based duration to it
dhours h = 12h+15min+99s+99ms;

// Get the value
cout << h.count();
```

Or alternatively, simply divide your integral based duration by one double-based `hours`:

```
cout << (12h+15min+99s+99ms)/1.0h << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {


    auto duration = 12.0h+15min+99s+99ms;
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<long double,std::ratio<3600,1>>>(duration).count();

}
```